# Double binomial series simplification

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Could someone please check that this double binomial series (with a delta function) simplification makes sense:

$$\sum_{m_J = -N/2}^{N/2} \sum_{m_K = -N/2}^{N/2} \dbinom{N}{N/2 +m_J}^{1/2}\dbinom{N}{N/2 + m_K}^{1/2} \delta_{m_K, m_J +1} = \bigg[\sum_{m_J = - N/2}^{N/2}\dbinom{N}{N/2 +m_J}^{1/2}\bigg]\bigg[ \sum_{m_J = - N/2-1}^{N/2} \dbinom{N}{N/2 + m_J + 1}^{1/2} \bigg] = \bigg[\sum_{m_J = - N/2}^{N/2}\dbinom{N}{N/2 +m_J}^{1/2}\bigg]^{2}$$

Please advise on the correct simplification if there are any inconsistencies. 
Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Upper case or lower case $m_J$ ? ... the first equality looks fine ... no idea how you did the next bit.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Look at the two factors on the RHS of the first equation. They seem to be equal to me. Consider the second factor, substitute $m_j = -\frac{N}{2}-1$ into $\dbinom{N}{N/2 + m_J +1}$ and you get $\dbinom{N}{N/2 + m_J}$ which is just the first factor. Hence the two factors are equal. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry John, changed my mind, I reckon the first equality should be $\sum_{m_J=-N/2}^{N/2-1} \binom{N}{N/2+m_J}^{\frac{1}{2}} \binom{N}{N/2+m_J+1}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ Note that when $m_J=N/2$ the second binomial coefficient will be zero, so we loose the last term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the case $N=2M$

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{m_J=-M}^M&\sum_{m_K=-M}^M\binom{2M}{M+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\binom{2M}{M+m_K}^\frac{1}{2}\delta_{m_K,m_J+1}\\
> &=\sum_{m_J=-M}^M\sum_{{-M\leq m_K\leq M}\atop{m_K=m_J+1}}\binom{2M}{M+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\binom{2M}{M+m_K}^\frac{1}{2}\\
> &=\sum_{m_J=-M}^{M-1}\binom{2M}{M+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\binom{2M}{M+m_J+1}^\frac{1}{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> The inner sum reduces to one summand with $m_K=m_J+1$. Since $\binom{2M}{2M+1}=0$ the upper limit of the outer sum can be set to $M-1$.

The calculation $N=2M+1$ follows similarly.

> **[Add-On 2017-04-10]:** We consider according to OPs comment
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J=-N/2}^{N/2}&\sum_{m_K=-N/2}^{N/2}\binom{N}{N/2+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\binom{N}{N/2+m_K}^\frac{1}{2}\delta_{m_K,m_J}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J=-N/2}^{N/2}\binom{N}{N/2+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\sum_{{-N/2\leq m_K\leq N/2}\atop{m_K=m_J}}\binom{N}{N/2+m_K}^\frac{1}{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J=-N/2}^{N/2}\binom{N}{N/2+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\binom{N}{N/2+m_J}^\frac{1}{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J=-N/2}^{N/2}\binom{N}{N/2+m_J}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J=0}^{N}\binom{N}{m_J}\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer. I just want to confirm one thing, had I instead had $$\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J = - \frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}} \sum_{m_K = - \frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}} \dbinom{N}{\frac{N}{2} + m_J}^{\frac{1}{2}} \dbinom{N}{\frac{N}{2} +m_K}^{\frac{1}{2}} \delta_{m_J, m_K}$$ would it follow that this is equivalent to $$\frac{m_J}{2^N} \sum_{m_J = -\frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}} \dbinom{N}{\frac{N}{2} + m_J} = m_J?$$ where I used the identity $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @JohnDoe: The calculation is somewhat different. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think we get the same result then, since in my comment, I meant to write
$$\frac{1}{2^N}\sum_{m_J = - \frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}} \sum_{m_K = - \frac{N}{2}}^{\frac{N}{2}} m_J \dbinom{N}{\frac{N}{2} + m_J}^{\frac{1}{2}} \dbinom{N}{\frac{N}{2} +m_K}^{\frac{1}{2}} \delta_{m_J, m_K} = m_j.$$
I forgot the $m_J$ in my comment. So this result is fine then?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Uppercase $J$, but yes, it is! :-)